Who maintains BTCRecover?
BTCrecover is often suggested as a tool for recovering partly forgotten wallet passwords etc. Who maintains this software?

As of December 2024 it seems ...

Christopher Guernee (guernec) created and maintained this tool until 2017
madacol made a fork adding P2SH support I think, but has not made any updates between 2017 and 2024.
3rditeration forked madacol's fork and probably was responsible for adding taproot support. There have been updates in 2024.

If I was using BTC recover I would download the source code of the most recently maintained version from what seems superficially to be the most respectable source. I would inspect the source code as far as I am reasonably able to. I would only run this on a machine that is completely isolated from the Internet and which would remain so until after its persistent storage was wiped clean.
